# Saving TTS as file with a custom voice (male voice)

Tags: android, text-to-speech

i have created a tts in male voice that is working perfectly, my working code is ,

```
    tts = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int i) {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                Voice voiceobj = new Voice("en-us-x-sfg#male_1-local",
                        Locale.getDefault(), 1, 1, false, null);

                tts.setVoice(voiceobj);
                String text = "Hai buddy, how are you?";
                tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null,null);

            }

        }


    });
```

**but i cant save this tts to file like .mp3 or .wav . do anyone have any idea for how to achieve this.?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [synthesizeToFile()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#synthesizeToFile(java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.os.Bundle,%20java.io.File,%20java.lang.String)).

```java
Voice voiceobj = new Voice("en-us-x-sfg#male_1-local",
        Locale.getDefault(), 1, 1, false, null);

tts.setVoice(voiceobj);
String text = "Hai buddy, how are you?";
tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null,null);
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, text);
// Define your destination file.
// Remember to create the directories in which the file will be inserted if they are not created yet.
final String dest = "/path/to/dest/file_name.wav";
// Write it to the specified file.
tts.synthesizeToFile(text, params, dest);
```